# Interface with a Generic property

Tags: c#, generics

i have a simplified version of the structure like this:

```
    public class ClassX { }
    public class ClassY { }

    public interface A<T>
    {

        T Data { get; set; }
    }

    public class B : A<ClassY>
    {
        public ClassY Data { get; set; }
    }

    public class C : A<ClassX>
    {
        public ClassX Data { get; set; }
    }
```

Then what i want to do is something like this:

```
    public class Example
    {
        public A Retrieve(string type)  // Point A
        {
            if (type == "B")
            {
                return new B();         // Point B
            }
            else
            {
                return new C();         // Point B
            }
        }
    }
```

So first issue is I cannot use the return type (Point A) of the method like above because i get this error for the return type:
`CS0305: Using the generic type 'A<T>' requires 1 type arguments`

Then i change the code to this, hoping that setting the generic type as `dynamic` would solve my problem:

```
    public class Example
    {
        public A<dynamic> Retrieve(string type)  // Point A
        {
            if (type == "B")
            {
                return new B();         // Point B
            }
            else
            {
                return new C();         // Point B
            }
        }
    }
```

But with that i get this error for Point B and Point C:
`CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type 'Ticketing.XF.B' to 'Ticketing.XF.A<dynamic>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)`

I am stuck at the moment. What would be a clean and proper solution to what i want to do?

Comment: Add a nongeneric base interface? I'm afraid what you have designer here is fraught with problems and there is no easy way out of it.

Comment: The problem is: you _think_ you have a common interface `A`, but you don't. You have n interfaces of type `A<T>`. `A<X>` not "is-a" `A<Y>`. And you cannot fake covariance by making T `dynamic`. That's just another `A<Z>` that is neither `A<X>` nor `A<Y>`.

Comment: But what is the _actual_ problem you are trying to solve? Obviously you want to have some sort of factory?

Comment: @Fildor yeah i want a factory there. The Data type will be different based on the class that is implementing the interface

Comment: Do `ClassX` and `ClassY` share an interface? If they don't _and_ they _cannot_ then your design has a flaw, because something is trying to do two completely different things.

Comment: no, they can be any type, string, DateTime, etc

Comment: Then, maybe you have to give a little more context. Right now, it still doesn't make too much sense to me. I feel like it would be better to have `object Data {get; set;}` and `Type DataType {get; set;}` which ... I don't know, still feels like doing something we shouldn't.

Comment: ^^ or... having `IDataHolder<TData>{ TData Data {get; set; }}`, you'd have only `public class DataHolder<T> : IDataHolder<T> { ... ` . Then you didn't even need a factory and could just do `new DataHolder<WhateverTypeYouNeed>()`

Comment: Something has to be in common between `ClassX` and `ClassY`.

Answer (score 1):

This can only be done through the interface for classes. The base interface cannot be generic if you want to use a factory method. Or you need to return a base type such as object

```
public interface IClass
{
    
}
public class ClassX : IClass { }
public class ClassY : IClass { }

public interface A
{
    IClass Data { get; set; }
}

public class BC<T> : A  where T : class, IClass
{
    public IClass Data { get; set; }

    public T As()
    {
        return Data as T;
    }
}


public class Example
{
    public A Retrieve(string type)  // Point A
    {
        switch (type)
        {
            case "B":
                return new BC<ClassX>();
            default:
                return new BC<ClassY>();
        }
    
    }
}
```

Comment: Mind that in `A myA = ExampleInstance.Retrieve("B");` , `BC::As()` will not be visible on `myA` ...

Comment: Usually describe the behavior in the IClass interface. But if you need a description of this method in A: public interface A2
{
 IClass Data { get; set; }
 T As<T>() where T : class, IClass;
}

public class BC2 : A2
{
 private readonly string _type;

 public BC2(string type)
 {
  _type = type;
 }

 public IClass Data { get; set; }

 public T As<T>() where T : class, IClass
 {
  switch (_type)
  {
   case "B":
    return new ClassX() as T;
   default:
    return new ClassY() as T;
  }
 }
}

Comment: But this doesn't make sense because then the calling code must know the type when calling As<T>. The best way to use the strategy pattern over the IClass interface

Comment: _"But this doesn't make sense because then the calling code must know the type"_ - you will find you always roll back to this if you do not question the whole purpose of the factory here. It is a x-y-Problem. We are trying to fix x, while the _actual_ problem is y.

Comment: Yes, we do not know the purpose of this method. But as we know generic classes are specific types. This means that the above option is not possible since one inherited type cannot be converted to another inherited type B<T>:A<T>, C<T>:A<T>, A<dynamic>

Comment: Exactly. That's what OP needs to understand, so he can drop this idea and figure out a design that actually solves his actual problem.